# SQL server 2008 concatenation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am concatenating Address fields to put street address together in SELECT statement of  SQL Server 2008 R2. How do I use IIF/CASE statement to add 'Apt#' if apartment field is not null?

```
SELECT ISNULL(RTRIM(StreetNo),'') + ' ' 
    +  ISNULL(RTRIM(StPfx),'')+ ' ' 
    + ISNULL(RTRIM(Street),'')   + ' ' 
    + ISNULL(Stfx, ' ') + ' ' 
    + ISNULL(RTRIM(Apt),'') HOME_ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(CASE WHEN Apt IS NOT NULL THEN 'Apt# ' + Apt ELSE '' END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(RTRIM(StreetNo),'') 
    + ' ' + ISNULL(RTRIM(StPfx),'')
    + ' ' + ISNULL(RTRIM(Street),'') 
    + ' ' + ISNULL(Stfx, ' ') 
    + CASE WHEN Apt IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' ' + RTRIM(Apt) END AS HOME_ADDRESS
```

In case `Apt` is not null, but is empty, I would write it like this:

```
    + CASE WHEN RTRIM(isnull(Apt, '')) = '' THEN '' ELSE ' ' + RTRIM(Apt) END AS HOME_ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on the fact that concatenating anything to a NULL is NULL;

```
... + ISNULL('Apt# ' + @apt, '')
```